# Decimal values are getting truncated in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store double value. After insertion in mysql, zeros in decimal in getting truncated.

```
Example:
1. 1.100 -> 1.1
2. 1.040 -> 1.04
```

How to avoid such truncations.

Comment: Whats wrong that. It stores actual value.

Comment: If you want to *see* the zeros, then use `format()`.  If you want to ensure three decimal places, then use the `decimal()` data type.

Comment: If you want to store WYSIWYG, change datatype to char.

Comment: Am not saying it is wrong. But i need to get the exact value i put. Previously i stored only two decimals where 1.10 stored as 1.1. After moving to three decimals, 1.100 is also stored as 1.1. How to differentiate the previous value with the new one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff where to use those functions?

Comment: Mathematically, `1.1 === 1.100`. You are confusing *value* with *rendering*.

Comment: @Bohemian i understand. Is there any way to identify, whether 1.01 in DB is either 1.01 or 1.010?

Comment: @vignesh yes: store it as a string, not a float. If you use a numeric type, trailing zeroes will always be trimmed.

Comment: You are trying to store a `double` value as what SQL datatype?